# React Native: What is the difference between calling props.aFunction and props.aFunction() with parenthesis?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This `TouchableOpacity` component: `<TouchableOpacity onPress={props.goToDetails()}>` takes props from its parent function, in this code, when calling the function `goToDetails` my code only works and shows the right results when using parenthesis, while sometimes when I just use the name of the function -in the class-, the code works fine without parenthesis: `onPress={this.goToDetails}`.
This is the full code,

In the class:

```
render(){
  return (
   <View>
     <MovieList results ={this.state.searchResults} goToDetails={()=>this.goToDetails} /> 
   </View>
)}

goToDetails=()=>{
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')
  }
```

Independent function:

```
const MovieList = props =>{
const renderItem = ({item}) =>(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.goToDetails()}>
        <Image source={{uri:`http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=&`}} style={{height:200, width:200}} />
        <Text>Title: {item.Title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>)

return (<FlatList style={{flex:1}} renderItem={renderItem} data={props.results}  />) }
```

UPDATE:
The class calling MovieList [code](https://github.com/EimanKDS/EimanKDS/blob/master/screens/SearchScreen.js), the TouhcableOpacity [code](https://github.com/EimanKDS/EimanKDS/blob/master/MovieList.js)

Comment: @larz yes, the `TouchableOpacity` code is in the MovieList function above, this function is not inside the class that calls `<MovieList />` , if that maybe the reason

Comment: @larz If you want to see the code for `TouchableOpacity` it's in the react-native source code: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity.js Eiman, can you update your question to include where you are rendering `MovieList` and passing a `goToDetails` prop so we can see how you are passing it?

Comment: @larz I added the links to my code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `goToDetails` callback inconsistently.

When you `goToDetails={()=>this.goToDetails}` this is a callback that returns a function, so in `Movielist` when it's attached to a handler as `onPress={props.goToDetails()}` it needs to be invoked immediately in order to get the returned function in order to again have a signature of `onPress={callbackFn}` or `onPress={e => callbackFn(e)}`.

```
render(){
  return (
   <View>
     <MovieList
       results={this.state.searchResults}
       goToDetails={this.goToDetails} /> // Pass callback as reference
   </View>
)}

goToDetails=()=>{
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')
}
```

MovieList

```
const MovieList = ({ goToDetails }) =>{
  const renderItem = ({ item }) =>(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={goToDetails}> // Attach callback to event handler
      <Image
        source={{ uri:`http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=&` }}
        style={{ height:200, width:200 }}
      />
      <Text>Title: {item.Title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      style={{ flex:1 }}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      data={props.results}
    />
  );
}
```